# Sensors - How to convert 4-20mA output to temperature and pressure values?

Tags: sensor, current-measurement, temperature, voltage-measurement, pressure

I'm dealing for the first time with two sensors, of pressure and temperature. Both have output of 4-20mA, then I'm using a 47 ohms 1% to convert to voltage. When flows 20mA, 20mA * 47 ohms = 940mV, and my ADC has a positive reference of 1V.

My doubt is about how to convert the mA value (or voltage on the resistor) to temperature (degrees) and pressure values (psi). I just didn't found documentation about that on both manufacturer's webpage.

Do they have linear relationship? For example for the temperature sensor, 4mA would mean 0°F, 20mA would mean 400°F and 12mA would mean 200°F?

These are the sensors:

TEMPERATURE SENSOR: [OMEGA OS136A-1-MA](https://assets.omega.com/manuals/MQS3946.pdf) Range is from -18 to 202°C (0 a 400°F).

PRESSURE SENSOR: [KELLER PA-21Y](https://download.keller-druck.com/api/download/8Ls5MtHNCdS8NgffyPLvee/en/2020-04.pdf) Its body show "range of 0 to 200 psi".

Regards.

Comment: you are right to assume a linear transfer function, unless otherwise specified in the datasheet of your sensor.

Comment: Life could be so easy with IO-Link....

Comment: Ugh. If you are using those decent industrial sensors with the dismally crappy ADC in the ESP8266, I would worry a **lot** more about the accuracy and linearity of the ADC than the sensors. Just assume they are linear with 12mA mid scale etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to search for a better data sheet such as [this one](http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/2339809.pdf?_ga=2.152260667.303508853.1594297161-282833041.1594297161&_gac=1.113112182.1594297161.Cj0KCQjwgJv4BRCrARIsAB17JI75we4YNwBhWXTF21P_L4xern87vXzF45NEMmzPgrnH3ta4THDMXOsaAlU_EALw_wcB) for the OS136A.

[image]

So, for the OS136-1 device, 4 mA represents 0 degF and 20 mA represents 400 degF. You can assume that the reading will be linear between these two points but, if in doubt, contact their sales team.

[Here's](https://download.keller-druck.com/api/download/8Ls5MtHNCdS8NgffyPLvee/en/2020-04.pdf) the PDF for the pressure sensor so I'd tak a look through it to check.

Comment: their datasheet does not show anything about the conversion I am refering to.

Comment: Who's data sheet? If it doesn't show stuff you need to know you need to speak to the supplier.